# reformat numbers stored in array

Tags: python, pandas

the input is:

[image: input of sample data]

need output as:

[image]

is this possible in just XL format or a python script is required.
if yes can you help with python script?
thanks.

my script:
my logic is read each df.col and compare value from 1 to 20, if equal write it out or write blank.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\my\scripts\test-file.xlsx")

print(df)

for column in df.columns[0:]:
    print(df[column])
```

Comment: You might want to share data as markdown tables

Comment: .. Or dataframe prints. The point is: data as pictures is considered "missing debugging details" on SO. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

**Sample df**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

df = pd.DataFrame({f'col_{i}': np.random.choice(range(1, 10), 
                                                size=4, 
                                                replace=False) 
                   for i in range(1, 4)})

df

   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      6      3      6
1      3      7      8
2      4      8      5
3      5      6      7
```

**Code**

```py
max_value = df.values.max()

out = df.stack()

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([out.index.get_level_values(1), 
                                 out.values])

out = (out
       .set_axis(idx)
       .unstack(0)
       .reindex(range(1, max_value + 1))
       )

out

   col_1  col_2  col_3
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN    NaN
3    3.0    3.0    NaN
4    4.0    NaN    NaN
5    5.0    NaN    5.0
6    6.0    6.0    6.0
7    NaN    7.0    7.0
8    NaN    8.0    8.0

# write away to excel with `df.to_excel`
```

**Explanation**

- Create a variable (`max_value`) for the max value in the `df` (to be used later for reindexing).
- Apply [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get all your columns as one stacked `pd.Series` (here: `out`).
- Now, create a new index (`idx`) using [`pd.MultiIindex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html). For the first array pick the second level from the index (use: [`pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values)); for the second array, use the *values*.
- Now, set `idx` as the index with [`Series.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html), apply [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), and use [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to add the missing index values (with `np.nan` values).